# Installing NVIDIA proprietary drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to install a proprietary graphics driver from NVIDIA (so I can run modern OpenGL) using the "additional drivers application". Whenever I try I can't do it. The progress bar after I select "apply changes" never moves no matter how long I leave it alone. It gets stuck at the beginning. Is there any way I can get this driver installed? (driver 361.42 for GeForce GT 610)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu version 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

This can work even if you have a problem in Additional Drivers (depending on what problem  it was).